# (Java) Internal work of add(obj o) method in ArrayList<obj>

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, copy, addition

As the title says, I'd like to know whether the add method makes a copy of the element and adds the copy to the ArrayList or copies the reference to the object for obvious performance reasons. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no copy or clone is made. The reference itself is added to the list pure and simple:

```
442     public boolean add(E e) {
443         ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
444         elementData[size++] = e;  // **********
445         return true;
446     }
```

On line 444 you see the actual reference being placed as an item of the ArrayLists's internal data array.

Otherwise the collection wouldn't work since it would not contain references to the actual objects of interest but rather to copies. As an aside, all this can be answered by looking at the source code which is available to you, either on your drive src.zip or online [here](http://grepcode.com/). As a second aside, your post suggests that adding a copy would improve performance. If this is so, why would you think so?

---

**Edit**
In comment you state:

> Maybe I was misunderstood, I meant that it was way quicker to copy the reference to the object.

As opposed to doing what? I'm not sure what other options you are envisioning. Object are represented by references, and so there's no other way to pass them.

Comment: Maybe I was misunderstood, I meant that it was way quicker to copy the reference to the object. Either way, your answer was truly helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @user3452637: you're welcome, but I'm still confused. Please check edit to answer.

Comment: @user3452637 Copying the reference isn't for "performance". The reference is copied, since storing an object into a list is defined as storing the reference. Retrieving that object from the list and acting upon it (say, with a setter) will affect the original object. In fact, many applications rely on the fact that objects are not cloned when inserted into data structures.

Comment: Right. Objects themselves are never "put" anywhere other than in the heap where they always reside until garbage collected. When you assign an object to a variable, you assign actually the reference to the object in the heap to that variable, and when you place an object into a collection, you place that same reference into the collection.

Comment: Right, it's just strange to start thinking in objects after I have been using imperative programming for a whole year, and here, most of the things that I had to code in C are already done here, and as I've been taught to implement algorithms in the most efficient way, I feel that in Java is more difficult to know how fast my program will run if I don't have years of experience. And about what you asked, i was saying it is faster opposed to first making a copy of the object and then storing it

Comment: There's no way to not copy the reference. You've already copied the reference just by calling the method, in fact. The useful thing to know is whether the object itself is copied (and the answer is no).

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Appends the supplied element to the end of this list.
 * The element, e, can be an object of any type or null.
 *
 * @param e the element to be appended to this list
 * @return true, the add will always succeed
 */
 public boolean add(E e)
 {
     modCount++;
    if (size == data.length)
       ensureCapacity(size + 1);
     data[size++] = e;
     return true;
 }
```

From [Source for java.util.ArrayList](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/ArrayList-source.html). Not exactly *from the horse's mouth* but should be close.